# How to get fontello to play with Meteor

Tags: meteor, fontello

I am trying to port my current project over to Meteor, which contains the standard fontello file structure:

```
css
    fontello.css
    ...
font
    fontello.eot
    fontello.svg
    fontello.ttf
    fontello.woff
```

I have ammended the fontello.css paths to point to the 'public' folder used by Meteor:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url('/font/fontello.eot?35453292');
  src: url('/font/fontello.eot?35453292#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/font/fontello.woff?35453292') format('woff'),
       url('/font/fontello.ttf?35453292') format('truetype'),
       url('/font/fontello.svg?35453292#fontello') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I have, therefore, moved the above mentioned 'font' folder into said 'public' folder.

In addition, I have created a new Meteor package, where the package.js file contains:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.0.3.1');
    api.addFiles('my-fontello.js'); 
    api.addFiles('font/fontello.eot', "client");
    api.addFiles('font/fontello.svg', "client");
    api.addFiles('font/fontello.ttf', "client");
    api.addFiles('font/fontello.woff', "client");
    api.addFiles('css/fontello.css', "client");
    api.addFiles('css/animation.css', "client");
});
```

I am not seeing any font icons being displayed - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As you put your files inside `public`, accessing files with from root folder will suffice(see following code for same) and pointers to your files as somewhat wrong i see as you put `#` and `?` in url, which shouldn't be there.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url(/font/fontello.eot);
  src: url(/font/fontello.eot) format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(/font/fontello.woff) format('woff'),
       url(/font/fontello.ttf) format('truetype'),
       url(/font/fontello.svg) format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

and for using it in package you need to start path from `public` as shown below

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.0.3.1');
    api.addFiles('tidee-fontello.js');  // put the location from root directory
    api.addFiles('public/font/fontello.eot', "client");
    api.addFiles('public/font/fontello.svg', "client");
    api.addFiles('public/font/fontello.ttf', "client");
    api.addFiles('public/font/fontello.woff', "client");
    api.addFiles('public/css/fontello.css', "client");
    api.addFiles('public/css/animation.css', "client");
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup with

```
client
  stylesheets
    fontello-social.css
public
  fonts
    fontello-social.eot
    fontello-social.svg
    fontello-social.ttf
    fontello-social.woff
```

I'm not using a package file at all.

In fontello-social.css the url paths for the 4 files are of the form /fonts/filename since "public" maps to "/"

Comment: In this case, I wanted to wrap Fontello up in a Meteor package of its own, as I need to control the load order of all my Meteor packages.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

1) Although I had created my package, I had not actually added it to my app. I therefore ran the command 'sudo meteor add my-fontello'.

2) There was no need to move any of the fontello assets to the public folder. Instead the fontello.css file was updated to this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontello';
    src: url('../font/fontello.eot?35453292');
    src: url('../font/fontello.eot?35453292#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/fontello.woff?35453292') format('woff'),
         url('../font/fontello.ttf?35453292') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/fontello.svg?35453292#fontello') format('svg');
         font-weight: normal;
         font-style: normal;
}
```

...and the package.js file was updated to this:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.0.3.1');
    api.addFiles('my-fontello.js'); 
    api.addFiles('font/fontello.eot', "client");
    api.addFiles('font/fontello.svg', "client");
    api.addFiles('font/fontello.ttf', "client");
    api.addFiles('font/fontello.woff', "client");
    api.addFiles('css/fontello.css', "client");
    api.addFiles('css/animation.css', "client");
});
```

It is also worth mentioning that in order for Meteor to pick-up the change made the the CSS file in this package, I needed to restart my Meteor app.